# Export a csv in js compatible IE

Tags: javascript, csv, export-to-csv

I need to generate a csv and then propose to download it.
It works on all browser except IE

```
var csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";
dataString = "name1,firstname1,addr1";  
csvContent += dataString; 
var encodedUri = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' +encodeURI(dataString);
window.open(encodedUri);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working solution

```
if (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {    
   var oWin = window.open();
   oWin.document.write('sep=,\r\n' + CSV);
   oWin.document.close();
   oWin.document.execCommand('SaveAs', true, fileName + ".csv");
   oWin.close();
}
```

Comment: What does your CSV value look like? Is it still starting with `"data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,"`?